# 80s Sci-Fi movie with a monster-astronaut

Tags: story-identification, movie

I will admit that this is very little information to go on; however, in the early 80s I was watching HBO and caught the tail end of a rather odd sci-fi movie.  I remember the "monster" being an astronaut (for some reason his suit was black/dark and rather sinister looking). It was a part of him or something, his face was slightly deformed for some reason. There was a scene where he was trying to make contact with his wife/ex-wife and he ended up crushing some car.  At the end, it showed a bunch of kids going through a space exhibit complete with empty spacesuits and pictures of the flight crew (I assume that they died or something... maybe a cover up dealing with the "monster" guy).

Like I said, very little to go on, this was at least 30 years ago for me so my memory is spotty.  I've been looking at IMDB and other sites through the years trying to find out the name of the movie, but given what I can remember, it is no small wonder I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187661/made-for-tv-scifi-movie-scientist-becomes-prototype-cyborg-fights-another-c (which is newer but has a confirmation comment from the OP)

Answer (score 10):

*[The Vindicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vindicator_%28film%29)* (also known as *Frankenstein '88* and known in Brazil as *Roboman*) is a 1986 Canadian science fiction film directed by Jean-Claude Lord. It has a protagonist in a blackened space-suit, a pregnant wife, an attempt to communicate, a crushed car, and a scene at the end with the suit being in a museum. All text below is from the Wikipedia summary with my highlighting.

[image: Movie Poster]

> Carl Lehman (David McIlwraith) is a **scientist working on a next-generation space suit** for the ARC corporation, run by the sinister Alex Whyte (Richard Cox), where all kinds of high-tech research is being conducted. One of these projects is developing "rage program" software that can sense when a user is provoked and take over its brain to destroy the attacker. After Carl confronts Whyte about some suspicious funding cuts, Whyte sends his employee Massey to kill him and disguise the death as a lab accident.
>
> ARC informs **Carl's pregnant wife Lauren** (Teri Austin) and daughter Catherine (Catherine Disher) that Carl has died. In reality, Whyte is keeping Carl's charred body in a suspension of oxygenating fluid which keeps his brain functioning. **Using Carl's space suit** and ARC's cutting-edge prosthetics technology, they build Carl a cyborg body and dub him "Project Frankenstein".

....

> Carl stows away on a garbage truck, which drops him into an incinerator. Thanks to his immense strength, he is able to break out and heads for his residence. On the way, some street thugs chase him into an alley, and he kills them in rage. **Realizing that the rage program forbids close contact with people, he talks to his wife from outside their house through a synthesizer in their living room**.

....

> Burt goes to the Lehman residence, where he confesses his lust for Lauren. Rebuffed, he subdues her by strangulation. Hunter later arrives and kills Catherine. Carl shows up in time **to crush Burt inside his car**, but Lauren gets captured and taken to ARC to lure Carl. Meanwhile, Whyte's girlfriend is being interrogated by the police, hinting that Project Frankenstein will be investigated and defused.

....

> Years later, Lauren is visiting a museum with her son Carl Jr. They **admire a display of Carl's space suit**, which has been successfully deployed on Mars.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the movie you are looking for is called *[The Incredible Melting Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Melting_Man)*. It's got a guy stuck in an astronaut outfit who starts melting I believe because he flew to close to the sun or looked at Saturn's rings. Then he starts killing people.

[image: Main character, melted]

Full movie:

Comment: The Mystery Science Theater 3000 version of this is watchable here: http://www.club-mst3k.com/704-the-incredible-melting-man

Answer (score 2):

*[The Vindicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vindicator_%28film%29)* is the movie you seek.

[image: Movie Poster]

Comment: I started out adding detail to this answer, then realized that I was completely changing it, so I reverted my changes and lodged my own answer.