# Late 50s early 60s sci-fi film: Astronaut becomes melded with his equipment

Tags: story-identification, movie

Does anyone know the title of a movie that featured an astronaut who went into space and returned mutilated with portions of his equipment embedded in him?

He was shown talking to his wife/girlfriend when he returned. This would have been the late fifties or early sixties. It seemed as though it was a double feature with the "Mysterians".

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [The Mysterians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterians) was released in 1959 but it was double-billed with [Watusi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watusi_(film)). Just pointing this out as it the last point of the post may be mistaken or referring to a location specific pairing of movies.

Answer (score 6):

"[First Man into Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Man_into_Space)" (1959)?

The year is close and the plot involves an astronaut coming back from space and visiting his girlfriend, which is against regulations. When he comes back from space again, he is a monster and looks like him and his spacesuit melted together. Below is the trailer.

Below is a picture of the transformed astronaut.

[image: Image of astronaut melded into spacesuit]

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain he went out to space? Because *[The Vindicator](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10110/80s-sci-fi-movie-with-a-monster-astronaut/107587#107587)* involves a man killed by his boss and revived as part of his space suit, and there's a scene where he talks to his wife over an intercom.

Here's a (non-English) trailer:

It's also a bit later than you were thinking with it having been released in 1986.